# C/C++ line number

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, line-numbers, dynamic-compilation

In the sake of debugging purposes, can I get the line number in **C**/C++ compilers?
(standard way or specific ways for certain compilers)

e.g

```
if(!Logical)
    printf("Not logical value at line number %d \n",LineNumber);
    // How to get LineNumber without writing it by my hand?(dynamic compilation)
```

Comment: @Lucas: Some of us prefer not to mess with debuggers. This kind of "poor person's assert statement" is sometimes more clear because it's a permanent part of the code, and enduring documentation of things that should be true about the state of the computation.

Comment: @Lucas: Debuggers are also less than useful for intermittent problems in long-running programs, or for collecting information about problems in software deployed at client sites.  In these cases, the only option is for the program to log as much information about the state of the program as possible, for later analysis.

Comment: @Lucas And debuggers don't work so well on some embedded systems to get this information.

Answer (score 228, accepted):

You should use the preprocessor macro `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`. They are predefined macros and part of the C/C++ standard. During preprocessing, they are replaced respectively by a constant string holding an integer representing the current line number and by the current file name.

Others preprocessor variables :

- `__func__` : function name (this is part of [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1642.html), not all C++ compilers support it)
- `__DATE__` : a string of form "Mmm dd yyyy"
- `__TIME__` : a string of form "hh:mm:ss"

---

Your code will be :

```
if(!Logical)
  printf("Not logical value at line number %d in file %s\n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
```

Comment: C99 uses \_\_func\_\_ rather than \_\_FUNCTION\_\_, which AFAIK is partially deprecated.  The difference can break your code, because \_\_func\_\_ cannot be used for C's constant string concatenation.

Comment: Reference from GCC manual: "\_\_FUNCTION\_\_ and \_\_PRETTY\_FUNCTION\_\_ were treated as string literals; they could be used to initialize char arrays, and they could be concatenated with other string literals. GCC 3.4 and later treat them as variables, like \_\_func\_\_. In C++, \_\_FUNCTION\_\_ and \_\_PRETTY\_FUNCTION\_\_ have always been variables."

Comment: Is there a way to get the line number as a string, same as the file name? I'd like the preprocessor to give me e.g. the string literal "22" instead of integer 22.

Comment: With regard to the text of the first argument to printf(), should the macro use in the second argument actually be `__LINE__-1,` in the example in this answer?

Comment: @sep332 Try this (untested!):
`char *convert_line_number(unsigned long line) {
  char line_string[15];
  sprintf(&line_string, "%ul", line);
  return (&line_string);
`
Call like so:
`int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("%s", convert_line_number(__LINE__);
  return (0);
}`

Comment: @sep332 Yes, but the cpp is a strange beast, so it must be done in two steps with macro arguments. `#define S1(N) #N` `#define S2(N) S1(N)` `#define LINESTR S2(__LINE__)` .  See http://c-faq.com/ansi/stringize.html

Comment: Strictly saying, `__func__` is not a macro, it's an implicitly declared variable.

Comment: @JosephQuinsey that's **not** true (not anymore, at least): `These identifiers are variables, not preprocessor macros, and may not be used to initialize char arrays or be concatenated with string literals.` (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)

Answer (score 74):

As part of the C++ standard there exists some pre-defined macros that you can use.  Section 16.8 of the C++ standard defines amongst other things, the `__LINE__` macro.

> **`__LINE__`:** The line number of the current source line (a decimal
>   constant).
>   **`__FILE__`:** The presumed name of the source file (a character string
>   literal).
>   **`__DATE__`:** The date of translation of the source file (a character string
>   literal...)
>   **`__TIME__`:** The time of translation of the source file (a character string
>   literal...)
>   **`__STDC__`:** Whether`__STDC__` is predefined
>   **`__cplusplus`:** The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the value 199711L when
>   compiling a C ++ translation unit

So your code would be:

```
if(!Logical)
  printf("Not logical value at line number %d \n",__LINE__);
```

Answer (score 23):

C++20 offers a new way to achieve this by using [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location).

The problem with macros like `__LINE__` is that if you want to create for example a logging function that outputs the current line number along with a message, you always have to pass `__LINE__` as a function argument, because it is expanded at the call site.
Something like this:

```cpp
void log(const std::string msg) {
    std::cout << __LINE__ << " " << msg << std::endl;
}
```

Will always output the line of the function declaration and not the line where `log` was actually called from.
On the other hand, with `std::source_location` you can write something like this:

```cpp
#include <source_location>
#include <iostream>

void log(const char* msg, const std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    std::cout << loc.line() << " " << msg << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    log ("test"); // Will print "10 test"
}
```

Here, `loc` is initialized with the line number pointing to the location where `log` was called.
[You can try it online here.](https://godbolt.org/z/Errfcodxe)

In older compiler versions, `std::source_location` might only be accessible as `std::experimental::source_location`.

Comment: "std::experimental::source_location" was merged into the mainline ISO C++ standard as of 7/2019. You can use "#include <source_location" and "std::source_location" now for C++20.

Answer (score 19):

You could use a macro with the same behavior as *printf()*, 
except that it also includes debug information such as 
function name, class, and line number:

```
#include <cstdio>  //needed for printf
#define print(a, args...) printf("%s(%s:%d) " a,  __func__,__FILE__, __LINE__, ##args)
#define println(a, args...) print(a "\n", ##args)
```

These macros should behave identically to *printf()*, while including java stacktrace-like information. Here's an example main:

```
void exampleMethod() {
    println("printf() syntax: string = %s, int = %d", "foobar", 42);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    print("Before exampleMethod()...\n");
    exampleMethod();
    println("Success!");
}
```

Which results in the following output:

> main(main.cpp:11) Before exampleMethod()...
>   exampleMethod(main.cpp:7) printf() syntax: string = foobar, int = 42
>   main(main.cpp:13) Success!

Comment: for c development, you would change the `#include` to `<stdio.h>`

Comment: `printf` is not [async-signal-safe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). So this macros can not be used in signal handlers.

Answer (score 11):

Use `__LINE__` (that's double-underscore LINE double-underscore), the preprocessor will replace it with the line number on which it is encountered.

Answer (score 10):

Checkout `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros

Answer (score 5):

Try `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`.
You might also find `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` useful.
Though unless you have to debug a program on the clientside and thus need to log these informations you should use normal debugging.

Comment: Why was I voted down on this and why did mmyers edit my post?

Comment: @Sanctus2099: It was edited, because Markdown transformed your double underscores to display FILE and LINE in bold font (don't you check how your answer looks like?). Another point might be (at least it looks to me this way now) that you gave an answer 1 hour after an already correct answer was given, so you added no value.

Comment: Double underscore is markup syntax for __bold__.  In order to properly display double underscores, you must escape them (like this: \\_\\_) or use backticks to mark them as `raw code` (like this: \`\_\_\`).  @mmyers attempted to help, but he only escaped one of the underscores, and thus you were left with the markup syntax for _italics_.  Downvotes are a bit harsh here, though, I agree.

Comment: Okay I didn't realize the thing about double underscores turning text into bold and I had to go and didn't have time to look at how my answer was looking. I do understand now. 
Even if my answer was an hour late it was still a good answer. It didn't add any value but it wasn't wrong either so no reason for downvote. That's what you get for trying to help...

Comment: @Sanctus2099 Some people are quick to down-vote, that's why it's important to make sure your answer is correct.  In this case, you posted a wrong answer and left it unedited for 4 hours.  You've got nobody to blame but yourself.

Comment: Sorry, it looked fine in the preview. My apologies.

Answer (score 5):

For those who might need it, a "FILE_LINE" macro to easily print file and line:

```
#define STRINGIZING(x) #x
#define STR(x) STRINGIZING(x)
#define FILE_LINE __FILE__ ":" STR(__LINE__)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since i'm also facing this problem now and i cannot add an answer to a different but also valid question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022436/how-to-get-the-file-name-and-a-line-number-of-a-function-call),
i'll provide an example solution for the problem of:
getting only the line number of where the function has been called in C++ using templates.

Background: in C++ one can use non-type integer values as a template argument. This is different than the typical usage of data types as template arguments.
So the idea is to use such integer values for a function call.

```
#include <iostream>

class Test{
    public:
        template<unsigned int L>
        int test(){
            std::cout << "the function has been called at line number: " << L << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        int test(){ return this->test<0>(); }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Test t;
    t.test();
    t.test<__LINE__>();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> the function has been called at line number: 0
>
> the function has been called at line number: 16

One thing to mention here is that in C++11 Standard it's possible to give default template values for functions using template. In pre C++11 default values for non-type arguments seem to only work for class template arguments. Thus, in C++11, there would be no need to have duplicate function definitions as above. In C++11 its also valid to have const char* template arguments but its not possible to use them with literals like `__FILE__` or `__func__` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773378/passing-const-char-as-template-argument).

So in the end if you're using C++ or C++11 this might be a very interesting alternative than using macro's to get the calling line.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `__LINE__`, but what is its type?**

> **LINE** The presumed line number (within the current source file) of the current source line (an integer constant).

As an *integer constant*, code can often assume the value is `__LINE__ <= INT_MAX` and so the type is  `int`.

To print in C, `printf()` needs the matching specifier: `"%d"`.  This is a far lesser  concern in C++ with `cout`.

**Pedantic concern:** If the line number exceeds `INT_MAX`<sup>1</sup> (somewhat conceivable with 16-bit `int`),  hopefully the compiler will produce a warning.  Example:

```
format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'long int' [-Wformat=]
```

Alternatively, code could force wider types to forestall such warnings.

```
printf("Not logical value at line number %ld\n", (long) __LINE__);
//or
#include <stdint.h>
printf("Not logical value at line number %jd\n", INTMAX_C(__LINE__));
```

---

**Avoid `printf()`**

To avoid all integer limitations: **stringify**.  Code could directly print without a `printf()` call: a nice thing to avoid in error handling<sup>2</sup> .

```
#define xstr(a) str(a)
#define str(a) #a

fprintf(stderr, "Not logical value at line number %s\n", xstr(__LINE__));
fputs("Not logical value at line number " xstr(__LINE__) "\n", stderr);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Certainly poor programming practice to have such a large file, yet perhaps machine generated code may go high.

<sup>2</sup> In debugging, sometimes code simply is not working as hoped.  Calling complex functions like `*printf()` can itself incur issues vs. a simple `fputs()`.