# Creating a custom class through #define macro

Tags: c++, programming-languages

I'm trying to create a macro with #define that'll allow me to create new class on demand. Here's my code:

```
#pragma once

#include "PDDefFileReader.h"

#define SET_LANG( lang ) *( new std::string( lang ) ) 

#define LANG( cName, lName )
class cName
{
public:
    cName()
    {
        _langName = SET_LANG( lName );                 <- HERE !!!!
        _reader = new PDDefFileReader( _langName );
    }
    ~cName(){}

    std::string Str(){ return _langName; }

private:
    PDDefFileReader* _reader;
    std::string _langName;
};
```

So I want to know how should I do it if I want the "lName" parameter of the define to be taken as a std::string object. For now (at the line "HERE !!!!") I get the error:

```
Error: Identifier "lName" is undefined
```

Any idea if what I want to do is possible ?

To give you some context, I'm doing a custom multi-language reader. So I could simply define new language by doing something like:

```
LANG( Cpp, "cpp" )
LANG( Perl, "pl" )
```

Thanks !!

Comment: -1 only use boiler-plate macros that are inserted by your IDE, not by your compiler's preprocessor

Comment: Why aren't you using templates for this ?

Comment: If these classes will differ only in a string variable, why have multiple classes? Why not one class with a constructor that takes a string argument?

Comment: `*( new std::string( lang ) )` is a memory leak. You just want `_langName = lName` or better still `_langName(lName)` in the initialiser list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your macro is empty, by default it does not continue to the next line unless you use a `\` at the very end, e.g.

```
#define #define LANG( cName, lName ) \
class cName \
{ \
    ...
```

Comment: wow... I didn't though the solution would be that simple. Thanks a lot man !!

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to use templates to solve your problem - this is really what they're for.

Unfortunately, the bad news is that template parameters while they can take most types do not handle `char*` or `char[]` at all. So:

```
template <char* TLang>
class
...
```

Is, unfortunately, illegal C++ in most use cases that matter, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773378/passing-const-char-as-template-argument) and its respective answers.

However, you *can* use templates to implement [policy based design](https://web.archive.org/web/20140719095905/http://www.altdev.co/2011/11/28/policy-based-design-in-c/) which is the first chapter (second?) of Modern C++ Design, and described in that link fairly well. The idea is that you inherit different (template-supplied) classes to implement different "policies".

This achieves the same effect as you are aiming for. Templates are generated at compile time for each instantiated value, so if I had a class:

```
cName<CppPolicy> CppName;
```

Then this would generate a `CppName` instance which is a class of type `cName` which inherits some policy capability from `CppPolicy`.

If I had to guess, I'd say you're about to decide what to do for a given language based on the value of that string  - that being the case, policy based design might be something you want to look at. This has the added advantage of avoiding large `if` statements involving string compares.

However, if you're literally just looking for string constants, why not simply use them, or as suggested in the comments supply the constant to an instance for each language?

As is, actually using `LANG` twice in the same module will produce a compile error, since you'll have *two* classes called `cName`.