# 'char const *str' as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, constants

Lets say i have a template:

```
template<char const *str>
class Template { ... };
```

Why is it not possible to write the following?

```
Template<"literal"> T;
```

or

```
char const *s = "Literal";
Template<s> T;
```

And why does the following works?

```
char const s[] = "Literal";
Template<s> T;
```

Comment: because the standard says so.

Comment: @yngum while that's true on a certain level, it's not very helpful as an answer.

Comment: @tenfour See [Passing const char* as template argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3854954/1508519). There is a pretty good explanation for the rationale behind not allowing it, but it comes down to speculation, doesn't it?

Comment: @yngum, is there a good reason that the standard says so? Or, is there a good reason not to allow the examples given?

Comment: It would be wonderful if someone explained the logic behind this language constraint! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because template classes are based on types and not on values.
templates are meant to help you write a more generic code, one that is the same for several types of data so you don't have to write it for each type all over again.

Comment: Templates can have type and non-type parameters. For example `template<int N> struct foo { double arr[N]; }; foo<3> my_foo;` is perfectly fine.