# C++ non-type template parameter const char*

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say we have

```
template <const char*>
struct A{};

// static storage
const char a[] = "asd";
const char* p = "asd";
```

This instantiation

```
A<a>{};
```

is okay for compiler. And this is understandable - array `a` decays to pointer to first element. But if we instantiate `A` with `p` like this

```
A<p>{};
```

compiler gives an error:

> error: non-type template argument of type 'char *' is not a constant expression

Why doesn't Standard allow to specify named variable of type `const char*` or just string literal `"asd"`, which is btw lvalue itself, as a template argument?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773378/passing-const-char-as-template-argument

Comment: I don't believe it's about lvalues as much as `p` doesn't have a precise memory location, but `a` does.

Comment: This is no different from `template <int> struct X{}; int p = 5; X<p> x;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The array `a` is a constant array of character, it's fully initialized at the time of compilation and also gets a know memory address by the compiler which is why it can decay to a pointer in a template.

But `p` is a *pointer* to a constant array of characters, but the pointer itself is not a compile-time constant, and can be changed to point to other strings, and it's is *not* initialized at time of compilation but either on time of linking (which happens after compilation) or when the program is loaded into memory. The address of `p` is known at time of compilation, but not the address of the string literal `p` points to.

---

To expand on the reason the address of the string literal is not known at time of compilation, it's because it's put in a special read-only segment by the compilers code-generator, and that read-only segment is then combined with the read-only segments from the other [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) when linking. This is why the final address of the string literal can't be known until the time of linking (at earliest).

Comment: thanks, makes sense. But why it doesn't work even if I use constexpr const char* p = "something"; ?

Comment: @Bikineev Same issue really, the location of string literals can't be calculated at the time of compilation, when it's needed for templates.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Excellent answer

Answer (score 0):

It may help to understand more why `A<p>{};` is not allowed if you imagine `p` is initialized by some function

```
const char* p = getP();
```

where `getP()` determines its result by some runtime data, for example, by reading a config file.