# Why aren't string literals constexpr by default?

Tags: c++, c++17

Why don't we make all string literals `constexpr`?

```
constexpr char name[] = "hello";

template < const char* N >
struct T{};

T < name > t;// this works fine
T < "hello" > t1; // this doesn't work
```

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46100477/1505939) for an alternative

Comment: Your template takes a char* not a char[], could this mismatch in types make a difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28809728/some-const-char-are-unavailable-at-compile-time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31504457/c-non-type-template-parameter-const-char

Comment: Basically, because two uses of "the same" string literal `"hello"` and `"hello"` are not required to be the same object. They can be two separate strings, just as the two "hello" strings in my first sentence are in two different places. So how can the compiler determine (especially when the definitions occur in two different translation units) whether `T<"hello">` and `T<"hello">` are the same type?