# reducing syntax "noise" without using a macro

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I'm trying to find a way of reducing a bit of syntax "noise" without resorting to a macro.  For the following code:

```
struct base { base() = delete; };    
struct tag1 final : private base
{
    static constexpr const char* name = "tag1";
};
template <typename T> std::string name() { return T::name; }
// ...
int main()
{
   const std::string name1(name<tag1>());
   return 0;
}
```

it would be nice to get rid of the some of the `static constexpr const char*` (not to mention the other) syntax as it gets annoying to repeat that for `tag2`, `tag3`, etc.  Plus, the only part of all of that which is really interesting is `tag1`, the rest is "noise".  The straight-forward solution *is* to use a macro:

```
#define MAKE_TAG(tag_name) struct tag_name final : private base { \
    static constexpr const char* name = #tag_name; }    
MAKE_TAG(tag2);
// ...
const std::string name2(name<tag2>());
```

The macro-based `MAKE_TAG(tag2);` syntax has removed all of the "noise" leaving `tag2` quite prominent.  An added benefit of the macro is that the `tag_name` can easily be turned into a string literal which prevents copy-paste errors.

An "obvious" possible solution might be to pass [`name` as a template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773378/passing-const-char-as-template-argument)

```
template<const char* name> base { ... };
struct tag3 final : private base<"tag3"> {};
```

but that's [not supported by C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3854954/8877).  A clever work-around, from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43413200/8877) below, is to use variadic template:

```
template<char... S> struct base { base() = delete;
    static std::string name() { return{ S... }; } };    
struct tag4 final : base<'t', 'a', 'g', '4'> { };
template <typename T> std::string name() { return T::name(); }
```

this does reduce much of the noise, but requires writing `'t', 'a', 'g', '4'` instead of `"tag4"`.  A run-time solution is fairly succinct

```
struct base {
    const std::string name;
    base(const std::string& name) : name(name) {} };    
struct tag5 final : base { tag5() : base("tag5") {} };
template <typename T> std::string name() { return T().name; }
```

but that's not entirely satisfying as `tag5` can now be instantiated, which ideally doesn't make sense.  Also, it's now necessary to write `tag5` three times, which isn't very [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Is there a way to further simplify (i.e., less typing) the code above?  ... without using a macro?

Comment: Note that `std::string` has no `constexpr` constructor, you will not be able to call `name` in a `constexpr` context.

Comment: It's not clear to me why anything other than the `static constexpr const char* name = "tag1";` is needed?  What is the purpose of all that other boilerplate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're willing to type out characters individually, we can do the following:

```
template<char... S>
struct base { 
    base() = delete;
    static std::string name(){
        return {S...};
    }
};

struct tag1 final : private base<'t','a','g','1'>
{using base::name;};
struct tag2 final : private base<'t','a','g','2'>
{using base::name;};
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Jl3YYMVNsXfHXLbR)

Call it like so:

```
std::cout << tag1::name() << std::endl;
std::cout << tag2::name() << std::endl;
```

I had to add `using base::name` in the derived classes because you're using private inheritance. If the inheritance becomes `protected` or `public`, then you don't need that.

The gist of the `name()` function in the base is to create a character array that we can construct a string from. We use [variadic parameter pack expansion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) to create the array.

Comment: @Ðаn: Sorry, it just didn't feel right to keep it. Regarding transforming "abc" into `a`, `b`, `c` at compile time. I don't think it's possible yet (well it might be with the use of macros, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of your question).

Comment: @Ðаn: It's debatable. [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QJCq8TvfSbIK0INf) is a kind of attempt at such a macro.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the name of the type, you can do it like this (at least for GCC):

```
    template <typename T> constexpr const char *get_type_name()
    {
        const char *name = __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;

        while (*name++ != '[');
        for (auto skip_space = 3 ; skip_space ; --skip_space)
        {
            while (*name++ != ' ');
        }

        return name;
    }

    // ...
    auto name1 = get_type_name<int>();
    auto name2 = get_type_name<tag1>();
```

The only drawback is that you have a trailing ']' at the end of the returned string.

If you are willing to drop the `constexpr` requirement, then you can easily delete that pesky last character.

Note that this is non-standard and non-portable.