# Alias Declarations for template members

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to generalize runtime attribute getter/setters for my classes with compile time declarations. I *thought* I could do something like this:

```
// header
class arguments {
public:
  template <typename T, char const *NAME> void set_id(T const &id)
  {
    ///..
    set(NAME, id);
  }
};

class test : public arguments {
public:
  using set_alpha = arguments::set_id<double, "Alpha">;
};

// cpp
int main()
{
  test obj;
  obj.set_alpha(47.11);

  return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2019 is giving my some `error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'set_id'`. Is there a way to specify member functions like this with C++17 or what am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing const char\* as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773378/passing-const-char-as-template-argument)

Comment: Thank you, but the const char* argument is only one part, in fact I'm struggeling more with the member function using declaration; since the problem is the same without a string template argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `using` for that, you have to write the method:

```
class test : public arguments {
    static constexpr const char AlphaStr[] = {'A', 'l', 'p', 'h', 'a', '\0'};
public:
  auto set_alpha(double d) { return arguments::set_id<double, AlphaStr>(d); }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/047e10880f00dae5)