# Inconsistent read of static member variable

Tags: c++, static

I would like to define timers which I could switch on and off in different files, without thinking about where I have to declare them, and what their scope should be. So I chose to use kind of global variables wrapped in a class with inline static variables, and the class is templated by the name of the timer :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

template<size_t N>
struct StringLiteral 
{
    constexpr StringLiteral(const char (&str)[N]) {std::copy_n(str, N, value);}
    char value[N];
};

template<StringLiteral>
struct GlobalTimer
{
    inline static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    inline static double totalTime = 0;

    inline static void on()
    {
        startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }
    inline static void off() 
    {
        auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        totalTime += std::chrono::duration<double>(endTime - startTime).count();
    }
    inline static double get()
    {
        return totalTime;
    }
};
```

In pratice I use them like this :

```
GlobalTimer<"myFirstTimer">::on();
//do some stuff
GlobalTimer<"myFirstTimer">::off();
//eventually in another file
std::cout << "myFirstTimer : " << GlobalTimer<"myFirstTimer">::get() << std::endl;
```

However, there's a problem I can't understand. In my multiple file code, this `get()` function always returns 0, while it works when I try it on a smaller example. Moreover, when I add `std::cout << totalTime << std::endl` before the return statement of the `get()` function, the timer works and doesn't return 0 anymore. So I thought it was a compiler optimization problem, but I tried to compile in debug, with gcc and clang, the result is the same. Now I think it may be an undefined behavior, so I came here to know the truth :).

**[EDIT]**

To remove uncertainty on uniqueness of string literals, I tried this :

```
constexpr char myFirstTimer[13] = "myFirstTimer";

GlobalTimer<myFirstTimer>::on();
//do some stuff
GlobalTimer<myFirstTimer>::off();
//in the same file this time
std::cout << "myFirstTimer : " << GlobalTimer<myFirstTimer>::get() << std::endl;
```

And this doesn't solve the problem, it returns 0...

**[EDIT 2]**

To remove the non standard StringLiteral non-type template parameter,  I tried with int instead :

```
template<int>
struct GlobalTimer
```

I still have the same problem.

Comment: You get different `StringLiteral` objects in two or more TU and different `GlobalTimer` instances, `on()`, `off()`, `get()` are called with different `GlobalTimer` instances each with own `totalTime` in different TU.

Comment: Since everything is static, I never use a GlobalTimer instance, only the class, but I get your idea. I don't understand why the different functions (on, off and get) would be called on different classes since the StringLiteral are built with the same argument in their constructor so they should be identical...

Comment: `const char[N]` literals are different, they just have equal contents, `StringLiteral` gets different instances. If it was simple, there would not be the known troubles with templates and string literals.

Comment: @273K So it means there's no way to make it work? I should use integer instead of this custom StringLiteral struct? I really don't get how the const char[N] can be different, why is that so?

Comment: @273K: Whereas `"myFirstTimer" == "myFirstTimer"` is not guaranteed, `StringLiteral<"myFirstTimer">{} == StringLiteral<"myFirstTimer">{}` should be...

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes that's exactly what I thought, in this case the problem eventually comes from elsewhere

Comment: Cannot reproduce [here](https://godbolt.org/z/3GebPW9YE) :/

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I know I have exactly the same problem, thank you for trying. I'll try to investigate further.

Comment: Sorry for the size mismatch, I changed the variable name between my code and here and forgot to change the size. Yes, I confirm that I have a template function defined in a header file, in which I call the three methods (on, off and get) with the same GlobalTimer<myFirstTimer>, and get returns 0...

Comment: `std::chrono::duration<double>` usage looks very weird to me

Answer (score 0):

In fact when you create an instance of `GlobalTimer<"myFirstTimer">` it generates different types, i.e. each static member and function for each of the type.

Template parameters should use `typename` or `class` keywords, or be integral.

Probably (because its UB) in your case the pointer is considered as a number (address), creating different types for each new address.

Here is the explanation: [Passing const char* as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773378/passing-const-char-as-template-argument)

Comment: Actually I'm not using a const char* as template argument. I'm using a StringLiteral with the constexpr constructor, whose argument is a const char *. So I think it should work and it doesn't explain why it works when I print ttotalTime value. I'll try valgrind to see if the error comes from an invalid read/write elsewhere in my code.

Comment: @AntoineMotte try to create a pointer to "myFirstTimer" and provide it instead of the phrase to all `GlobalTimer<myptr>`. If my suggestion is correct, the pointer would have constant address and it will start working.
This check is simple and would prove my point.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about program design. Instead of make everything static, we can make static once. It more simple. And try do not use template until you understand overloaded function.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct StopWatch{
    using clock_type = std::chrono::system_clock;
    std::chrono::time_point<clock_type> start_at;
    std::chrono::time_point<clock_type> end_at;
    void on(){
        start_at = clock_type::now();
    }
    void off(){
        end_at = clock_type::now();
    }
    template<typename R = std::chrono::milliseconds>
    R duration(){
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<R>(end_at - start_at);
    }
};

StopWatch& get_global_watch(){
    static StopWatch w{};
    return w;
}

int main(){
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
 
    auto& global_watch = get_global_watch();//this is just temporary reference for convenience to writing code

    global_watch.on();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1.5s);

    get_global_watch().off();

    std::cout << "duration=" << get_global_watch().duration().count() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more investigations, I think it's the strangest bug I've ever seen. I modified the code to print the address of totalTime at each step and ran it in a debugger :

```
template<StringLiteral>
struct GlobalTimer
{
    inline static std::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    inline static double totalTime = 0;

    inline static void on()
    {
        startTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "ptr in on :  " << &totalTime << std::endl;
    }
    inline static void off() 
    {
        auto endTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        totalTime += std::chrono::duration<double>(endTime - startTime).count();
        std::cout << "ptr in off :  " << &totalTime << std::endl;
    }
    inline static double get()
    {
        std::cout << "ptr in get :  " << &totalTime << std::endl;
        return totalTime;
    }
};
```

And in the file where I'm calling these functions I have :

```
auto ptr = &GlobalTimers<"myFirstTimer">::totalTime;
std::cout << "ptr in file : " << ptr << std::endl;
GlobalTimer<"myFirstTimer">::on();
//do some stuff
GlobalTimer<"myFirstTimer">::off();
int time = GlobalTimer<"myFirstTimer">::get();
std::cout << "*ptr : " << *ptr << std::endl;
std::cout << "time : " << std::endl;
```

It prints in the console the following :

```
ptr in file : 0x55a8a9c81880
ptr in on :   0x55a8a9c81880
ptr in off :  0x55a8a9c81880
ptr in get :  0x55a8a9c81880
*ptr : 0.000502791
time : 0
```

The pointers are all the same, so there's absolutely no doubt that the template class is unique and that the bug doesn't come from here (and as I said before, I observed the same behavior with an int template parameter).

**And here is the most strange thing I have ever seen** : in the debugger, the variable `GlobalTimer<"myFirstTimer">::totalTime` (accessed via a watchpoint defined as `*ptr`) has a correct non-zero value after off() is called. When the get() function is called, the variable totalTime is non zero, but the instruction `return totalTime;` returns 0. I've never seen such a strange thing...

Actually when pausing the execution in the get() function. The debugger has a value of totalTime which is 0, although the address of totalTime is right and the value of *ptr outside the get() is non-zero. I really can't explain what's happening here.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem, and I feel so stupid. In my real code I have an intermediate function `T_GET<timerName>()` which is shorter to write than `GlobalTimer<timerName>::get()`. I accidentally defined its return type to int so the timer is always round to 0 because it is always smaller than 1 in the examples I tested...

I'm really sorry for all these posts. Actually this bug occurs in this class which is templated by a StringLiteral and has static variables. As everyone here (obviously no one could have found the bug since it wasn't in the post...), I was focused on these specific points because it's the first time I used them together, but the problem was far more simple than that.

So to conclude, I can say that there are no problem at all with using StringLiteral as non-type template parameters. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You might probably delete the question then.

Comment: Hi @Jarod42, I can't delete it, it says that other people have invested time into answering the question, sorry for that...