# getting thread name from thread id using posix api

Tags: c++, posix

i have a requirment that i have to get thread name from thread id or if that is not possible how to get thread name. Here i am not creating the thread. I am creating the library and this library is used by application and library code will be running in application thread context, i want to print thread name in console log to know that log is comming this particular thread. This should be achieved using posix api's so that it should be portable.

Thanks in advance all for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, posix threads don't have names, but you might use [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) to store a name.  See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzahw/rzahwex1.htm) for an example (not with strings).

Comment: Wouldn't that only help with the name of the current thread, anyways?

Answer (score 2):

**There's no such thing**. But there are informations besides the **thread id** that might be useful to add to your log, such as the time of the call, the **filename** of source code and the **line number** where the call was executed.

Comment: can u pls specify what are the api's or any link where i can find the info or atleast function name of thread that thread is executing

Comment: @user519882 My apologies, a better reference is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849832/c-c-line-number/2849850#2849850

Answer (score 0):

There is no POSIX api to attach a name to a thread.

On Linux you can do `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, ...)`. See `man prctl`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seem `pthread_getname_np()` and `pthread_setname_np()` in `pthread.h`, to obtain and set the display name of a thread, respectively. However, it is surrounded by conditionals, suggesting it is a nonstandard GNU extension.

You might want to examine the `pthread.h` you are compiling against and see if the functions are defined. If your code needs to be portable, be sure to enclose these calls in conditionals.