# How to display the line number of my source code in printf

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C/C++ line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849832/c-c-line-number)

I want to display the line number where the printf is triggered?

It may look like this:

```
printf("the line number is: %d",SOME_LIBC_MACRO);
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `__LINE__` macro

```
printf("the line number is: %d", __LINE__);
```

Lists of other pre-defined macros are available for [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) and [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: @unwind Thanks for the link and typo correction. I'd just found that link to pre-defined macros but you beat me to it.

Comment: also, some compilers support __func__ or __FUNCTION__ however, it's not a standard one.

Comment: @anishsane `__func__` is standard; it's defined in [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (§6.4.2.2) and [C++11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) (§8.4.1). `__FUNCTION__` is non-standard but implemented by many compilers (some require certain flags to enable it).

Comment: I think, I should have `back-quoted` `__func__` :-)