# Getting caller function line number in glog

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, glog

I have to implement a logger class, taking a log id, and printing the necessary information, pre-read from xml code. Initially, I have a problem of logging the file name and line number.

Before when I used glog in main.cpp,

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = logs.find(logId);
LOG(ERROR) << logId;
```

it was printing

```
E0803 10:16:57.219295 10244 main.cpp:129] Incorrect input
```

Now I moved the function inside my logger wrapper. I'm (as expected) getting :

```
E0803 10:17:03.587898 10244 DummyLogger.cpp:65] Incorrect input
```

Everyting is logged gives the same line number of DummyLogger.cpp class now (as expected). But I would like it to print the caller's name and line number. Is that possible?

Comment: You have to create MACRO which calls `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`.

Comment: That's the only way I suppose. I had already checked this 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849832/c-c-line-number)

But I was wondering if that could be possible to configure glog