# C ++ how to get line number and function name in overloaded "new" operator

Tags: c++

I want to overload new operator in a multi threaded environment and want to have thread id, function name and line number inside that. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Until there is http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location, you have to rely on MACRO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C/C++ line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849832/c-c-line-number)

Comment: If you try to do that in the operator, you will always get the name and line number of where `operator new` is defined, not the place where it is called.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to give much more details and *motivations*

Comment: @Jarod42: Interesting. Seeing how that will be implemented in the library, I wonder how they'll make it work since the whole thing is declared `constexpr` and whenever I use `__FILE__` my compiler tells me "not a constant expression".

Comment: @Damon: Contrary to some classes of `std`, that will indeed require help of compiler (as it already helps for `__FUNC__`, `__LINE__`, for some traits...).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

You can make a new `operator new` overload:

```
void * operator new(std::size_t count, const char* file, int line)
{
    // Do stuff
    // ...
    return ::operator new(count);
}

void * operator delete(void* p, const char* file, int line)
{
    // Do stuff
    // ...
    return ::operator delete(p);
}

// ... and [] versions ..
```

Then you can use placement syntax:

```
auto x = new (__FILE__, __LINE__) Foo;
```

And then you can add a macro:

```
#define TRACE_NEW new (__FILE__, __LINE__)

auto x = TRACE_NEW Foo;
```

Comment: No, you are not overloading *placement new* but simply adding a global `operator new` and using that in `TRACE_NEW`. [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) is something different like e.g. `void* p = mmap(`....`); auto x = new(p) Foo;`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yeah, "placement new" was wrong. The Standard calls them "placement allocation functions" which is obviously not the same thing. Perhaps this wording is better.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is no way to do what you want (except of course by using macros like [moldbnilo answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114788/841108), or some future [std::source_location](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/source_location))

However, if you are on a recent Linux system, and if all your code (and most of the libraries it is using, including `libstdc++`) is compiled with debug options, you might also consider Ian Taylor's [libbacktrace](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace) (it is also used inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and use it inside your `operator new` implementation.  That `libbacktrace` enables you to inspect call frames in your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) using [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug info.

You could then even have the source location of most functions in your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (notably the source location in the caller of your `operator new`).

Remember that you can compile some C++ code (using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)) with both debug info (e.g. `-g`) and some optimization flags (e.g. `-O1` or perhaps `-O2`); of course the debug info (in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF)) would then be "fuzzy" but still mostly usable in practice.

BTW, perhaps you just need [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) or some address sanitizing by compiling with `-fsanitize=address` [instrumentation option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) (we don't know because your question is not motivated).